# How to center vdots in table?

Tags: tables

I have a table that looks like this:

```
\begin{table*}[tb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{M{2.20cm}|M{2.50cm}|M{2.50cm}|M{3.00cm}|M{3.50cm}|M{2.5cm}}
%\toprule
\hline
    $\mathsf{Game}_0$ & $\mathsf{Game}_1$ & $\mathsf{Game}_2$ & $\mathsf{Game}_3$ & $\mathsf{Game}_4$ & $\mathsf{Game}_5$       \\
\hline
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots                             \\
%\midrule
    $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ & $\f$      \\
%\midrule
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
%\bottomrule
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sequence of games.}
\label{tab:games}   
\end{table*}
```

However, the vdots are not centered in the columns. Any ideas how to center them?

Comment: Please make your example code compilable. How is the `M` column type defined? How is `\f` defined?

Comment: Does "center" refer to vertically or horizontally centering the dots? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{M{2.20cm}|M{2.50cm}|M{2.50cm}|M{3.00cm}|M{3.50cm}|M{2.5cm}}
%\toprule
    \hline
\mathsf{Game}_0 & \mathsf{Game}_1 & \mathsf{Game}_2 & \mathsf{Game}_3 & \mathsf{Game}_4 & \mathsf{Game}_5       \\
    \hline
\vdots    & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots                             \\
%\midrule
    a & b & c & d & e & f      \\
%\midrule
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
%\bottomrule
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Sequence of games.}
\label{tab:games}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Above solution is based on guessing about your definition of `M`, `f` and page layout. As you see, contents in all cell are in math mode.

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected!